# SSIS derived column expression - convert datetime variable + string variable to date time

Tags: variables, ssis, expression, derived

Hi and thank you in advance for any help.

Essentially what I need is a derived column expression that shows the following that will then go into a datetime field in a SQL table:

"Today's date" + "08:00"

e.g. 
Today would be       2014-12-04 08:00
Tomorrow would be    2014-12-05 08:00
etc.

Thank you again.

Mally.

Comment: What part of it don't you know how to do?

Comment: Hi and thanks. It's the complete structure of the expression and how to get it back to a date time. For example I've tried   RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,2,1252)DATEPART("dd",GETDATE()),2) + "-" + RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,2,1252)DATEPART("mm",GETDATE()),2) + "-" + (DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART("yy",GETDATE()) + " " + "08:00"  but i can't get it back to date time.  I know the code I've used gives a different order to what i want.

Comment: And does it sit in its own expression?

Answer (score 0):

If the desired end result is a datetime data type, what about this?   The inner DATEADD() gets midnight of today, and the outer DATEADD() adds 8 hours to it.

```
DATEADD("hh",8,DATEADD("dd",DATEDIFF("dd", (DT_DATE)0 ,GETDATE()), (DT_DATE) 0))
```

Comment: Thanks.  when I've put this into my expression it give errors saying that "The function datediff does not support the data type DT_14